# Is it possible to obtain a 12×12 carpet by cutting a 16×9 carpet once?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

Yesterday my brother asked me a question.

> Suppose you have a carpet of size $16×9$. Now you have to cut this carpet in such a way that after cutting it and arranging pieces, the dimension is $12×12$. You can only cut the carpet once. You can arrange the obtained pieces in any way you like.
>   How can you do this?

Comment: if you cut 144 equal sized  square pieces this should work yes

Comment: @marmouset One cut!

Comment: If the breadth$=9$ units, how will it gain the other $3$ units?

Answer (score 4):

[image]
Essentially the same problem appears in Boris Kordemsky's puzzle book, with the solution as below.
[image]

Comment: I think you don't have to divide to same shape.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Whether the two pieces are the same shape or not was not specified in the question.

Comment: Here is no explanation why stair-step cut work well, and that is unique solution, so on.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki I don't have to prove that the solution is unique, nor "why the stairstep cut works well". The proof is the picture; I only have to give one solution.